# Controller testing with rpec and factorygirl in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm attempting to create some controller specs in my Rails 5 app using rspec, but the code keeps throwing the following error:

```
1) SessionsController Log in and log out logs in with valid user
   Failure/Error: user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)

   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

My spec is pretty straightforward. The user instance variable uses factory-girl to create a user with the email "user@example.com" and password as "password." When I call puts on these variables, I can see that they are set correctly.:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe SessionsController, type: :controller do
  before :each do
    @user = create(:user)
  end

  describe "Log in and log out" do
    before :each do
       post :create, { session: { email: @user.email,
                                  password: @user.password }}
    end
    it "logs in with valid user" do
      puts @user.email + " " + @user.password
      expect(is_logged_in?).to be_truthy
    end
  end
end
```

Finally, the code from the sessions controller is below:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      remember user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Am I misunderstanding the way params are sent to the controller in rspec? Is there any other reason for this error to be returned?

Comment: Instead of checking `puts @user.email + " " + @user.password`, you should check `params[:session]` inside your controller action. That is `nil` as per the error message.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that by declaring the params a line earlier and calling puts params before the post statement. Parms is putting `{:session=>{:email=>"example@user.com", :password=>"password"}}` which is only making me more confused. It seems like everything is assigned right to me?

Comment: You got it wrong. I asked you to check params in controller action after you call `post :create, ...`

Comment: It looks like params[:session] is returning this string `example@user.com password` I have no idea why it wouldn't be returning a hash, however since I am defining it as a hash.

Answer (score 0):

Changes were made in Rails 5 to the way you send params in controller tests.

Instead of:

```
before :each do
  post :create, { session: { email: @user.email,
                             password: @user.password }}
end
```

You need to provide the `params` key in post request attribute hash. Like so...

```
before :each do
  post :create, params: { session: { email: @user.email,
                                     password: @user.password }}
end
```

It's subtle, but it's different. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Some more information can be found here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/867

However, in this case don't get confused between the actual session, and your SessionController params.